# jquery: Make divs large or small depending on text length

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, canvas

I want to develop a stable webpage that adapts well to all screen sizes including mobile devices. My idea is to create a script that would check the length of text in a div. If it contains:

- few or equals than 20 words, make the div small
- between 21 and 500 words make the div normal
- and more than 500 words maxe the div big.

I also want to use a toggle to hide content but for the moment it would be okay. I am using isotope to stack divs vertically. And am loading texts from a mysql database query.
I want the articles that are low in content which could be links or youtube videos to show in smaller boxes while normal and big articles gets displayed big enough to avoid seeing scrollbars or not before it reaches an understandable maximum size. I'll have to find a way to deal with it without unbalancing the site's shape.

Can someone tell me what I have to do?

Comment: You could just set `min-height` and `max-height`.

Comment: responsive (fluid) DIV elements is what you mean? Normally, DIVs take the height of the content automatically, you just need CSS

Comment: I need something such as <? $message="as"; if (strlen($message)<8) { $view= "32px"; } else if (strlen($message)>64) { $view= "64px"; } else { $view= "128px"; } echo '<div class="wid" style="width:'.$view.';">'.$message.'</div>'; ?> But java side :P

Just like this from DGS's answer
$('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length < 80){
        //small
        $(this).height(50);
    }else if($(this).text().length < 2000){
        //mid
        $(this).height(150);
    }else{
        //large
        $(this).height(350);
    }
});

All i need to know is how to use it :/ im a java noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your divs `height:auto` so that the more text that is added to the div the larger they become.

Or if you want to use jQuery

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length < 80){
        //small
        $(this).height(50);
    }else if($(this).text().length < 2000){
        //mid
        $(this).height(150);
    }else{
        //large
        $(this).height(350);
    }
});
```

I used characters as a limit rather than words because words can be unreliably with length. If you want to use words instead you will have to split on spaces or use regular expressions but you will find that the end result wont be as pleasing

Comment: this would be a valid answer (even if this makes no sense at all ;-) )

Comment: i just found this... What could i add to make it perfect?

I put this in a fluxbb procedure

<?
$message="as";
if (strlen($message)<8) {
  $view= "32px";
}
else
if (strlen($message)>64) {
  $view= "64px";
}
else {
  $view= "128px";
}


echo '<div class="wid" style="width:'.$view.';">'.$message.'</div>';


?>

Comment: Matthieu, is this PHP? You have never mentioned that you need a solution for PHP or templates ... A clean and pure jQuery solution would be better

Comment: `strlen($message)` isn't going to tell you how many words are in `$message` but otherwise that is nearly the same thing i did in jQuery just in php

Comment: yeah the jquery solution is perfect :P it's also equivalent ^^
the php workaround also works... I just need to estimate the size, the amount of words is useless. I'll try the jquery code just now ^^ thank's

Comment: I may look like a total noob and i swear i am... With PHP it's easy to replace a value... But with java... I'm much like messed... How do i use this?